# dynamically delete controls from table

Tags: c#, winforms

Am trying to delete textboxes and labels while their names which have equal value from the selected items from the listbox. If i run this code only the first if statement is executed and removing only the label controls inside the table.

I must also mention that controls of the table are dynamically created.

```
    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (Control t in table2.Controls)
            {
                if (t is Label && t.Text==listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    table2.Controls.Remove(t);
                    continue;
                }
                if (t is TextBox && t.Name.Contains(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
                    table2.Controls.Remove(t); continue;
                }
            }
            listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItems[i]); i--;
        }
    }
```

This is how controls are created indide the table.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        this.table2.Controls.Clear();
        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
          table2.Controls.Add(new Label() { Name = item.ToString(), Text = item.ToString(), AutoSize = true });
          table2.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Name = item.ToString(), AutoSize = true });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this code is incorrect listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItems[i]); i--;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove an item from a collection (suppose the item at position 0), the item at the next position (postion 1) shifts in position zero. But your for loop execute the next iteration and your indexer becomes 1 and so it terminate the loop.

The first approach to avoid this is to loop in reverse order, from the end of the collection toward the begin of it

But you could also simplify a lot your code with

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = listBox2.SelectedItems.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        // This is our search term...
        string curItem = listBox2.SelectedItems[i].ToString();

        // Get only the controls of type Label with Text property equal to the current item
        var labels = table2.Controls
                     .OfType<Label>()
                     .Where (c => c.Text == curItem)
                     .ToList();
       if(labels != null)  
       {
          for(int x = labels.Count()-1; x >= 0; x--)
             table2.Remove(labels[x]);
       }


       // Get only the controls of type TextBox with Name property containing the current item
       var boxes = table2.Controls
                          .OfType<TextBox>()
                          .Where (c => c.Name.Contains(curItem)
                          .ToList();

       if(boxes != null)  
       {
          for(int x = boxes.Count()-1; x >= 0; x--)
             table2.Remove(boxes[x]);
       }
       listBox2.Items.Remove(curItem); 
    }
}
```

Comment: angelos_cle are you sure nothing happened can you post the decremented code block so that we can see if you have a typo in your code..? also by typo I meant to say `Logical Errors`

Comment: wow do you know of any tutorials of explaining this way of writing your answer?

Comment: oops.still not deleting all of the controls from the table. only the first controls from first item

Comment: LINQ, It is a long road but a very productive one. Start here with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx or here http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq

Comment: IN your example above you build a list with only one label and one textbox. Do you have more than one label or textbox with the same text or with similar names?

Comment: multible textboxes and labels exist while multiple listitems are selected from the listbox

Comment: still not working . only the first item(label and textbox) is removed

Comment: Got it. SelectedItem vs SelectedItems..... you should use SelectedItems[i] in the search code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58620/discussion-between-steve-and-angelos-cle).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you decrementing your iterator at the end of your for loop? It looks like you're stuck in the loop, buddy.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer!